# awaitMessages not taking my input when I run it. I'm trying to make a discord bot with node.js and discord.js

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, new-operator

Just started coding today and looking at some examples. Trying to make a quest giver bot but the input does not work after I tried to add more choices.

client.on('message', message => {
    console.log(message.content);

```
if(message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}explore val`)) {
    //message.channel.send("Testing message.", { files: ["./quest/stone-men-2.gif"] });
    message.channel.send("test.");
    message.channel.send("test ");
    message.channel.send('What will be your course of action? This will await will be cancelled in 30 seconds. It will finish when you provide a message that goes through the filter the first time.')
        .then(() => {
            message.channel.awaitMessages(response => response.content === 'A', 'B', 'C', {
            max: 3,
            time: 30000,
            errors: ['time'],
    })
        .then((collected) => {
            message.channel.send(`The collected message was: ${collected.first().content}`);
    })
        .catch(() => {
            message.channel.send('There was no collected message that passed the filter within the time limit!');
    });
```

});
    }})

No error messages, it runs just doesn't work on my discord.